# How do I generate RSS feeds for YouTube channels with non-English characters in their names?

Tags: youtube, rss, special-characters

I create RSS feeds for YouTube channels using this formula:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=**channel or user name**
```

But this method doesn't seem to work for, for example, [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAY2wkEFE8JwK_mctIMtcJw/videos). I guess this is due to the fact that non-English characters are present in the title/user name.

Answer (score 1):

The real channel for your example is

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAY2wkEFE8JwK_mctIMtcJw/
```

The channel ID is : `UCAY2wkEFE8JwK_mctIMtcJw`

The model for RSS feed is

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=ChannelID
```

So, here the feed is

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAY2wkEFE8JwK_mctIMtcJw
```

If the channel ID has been renamed in the main URL... just look at the source code of the channel and search for `channelId`. You'll find the channel ID just on the right.

For example:

```
channelId" content="UCAY2wkEFE8JwK_mctIMtcJw">
```

### Export Method

Given that you've subscribed to the channel, an alternative method for finding the RSS feed is to export your subscriptions from your [Manage Subscriptions](https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager) page. Clicking on the **Export Subscriptions** button at the bottom of the page will allow you to download an XML file that has the channel names and RSS feeds for all subscribed channels.